# Redirect all www to non-www including subdomains

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have two separate WordPress sites on the same domain, one installed in the following way:

```
http://subdomain1.domain.tld and http://subdomain2.domain.tld.
http://domain.tld redirects to subdomain1.
```

I need to remove all www. to non-www (this now works as tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), www.domain.com now returns domain.com  but i am still getting a 404 page returned when i type in a subdomain prepended with www.

My current code, with the suggestions by @icabod now looks like this.

```
# 301 redirect www to non-www url
# including subdomains

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
   RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

`mod_rewrite` is working with other redirections, I do not want to use a PHP redirection. I have no access to my registrar's CNames so I cannot redirect them through there. I have placed a `.htaccess` file in which I have the below code in the root folder and have tried placing it in the subdomains root folder as well.

This is driving me bananas !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can use a part of the `RewriteCond` expression in the rule, just like you can match a part of the `RewriteRule` expression:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R]
```

The `%1` matches the part in braces in the `RewriteCond`, and the `$1` matches the part in the `RewriteRule`. This rewrite does make the assumption that you are only using http on the standard port 80, but will basically remove any `www.` from the beginning of the requested URI.  From that point, redirecting `domain.tld` to `subdomain1.domain.tld` should be straightforward:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain1.example.com/$1 [R]
```

---

As an aside, you probably shouldn't be using `[R=301]` until you have the rewrite working correctly, as the `301` means it's a permanent rewrite, but during testing it is prone to change.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it does indeed remove the www from www.domain.tld but it does not however remove the www from www.subdomain.domain.tld, i cannot understand why but this is what i need, perhaps i didn't explain that very well in my question.

Comment: It should remove the beginning `www.` from any http host (you can test it out on [made-with-love](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)), so I would guess that you have some other rule which is setting the www on the sub domain.

Comment: You are right; it does indeed remove the www from both the main domain including subdomains; at least in the link you sent me (thanks for that tool btw!) when i live tested it still returns a 404 though :/